# Supressing windows.load events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was experimenting with a chrome extension I created over some websites. Lets say the plugin print the site web address When the whole page completes loading. So in the plugins js code I have a line like this:

```
window.onload=function(){

var address = document.location.href;
console.log(address);

}
```

It works fine for most of the site, but there was one site, on which the console didnt show any output. Can window.load be suppressed?, if yes how to overcome it?

I tried using `window.addEventListener("load", myfunction, false);` still no luck!

Thanks

Comment: Is it `window.onload`?

Comment: yeah sorry, made the edit

Comment: check if any other onload event gets fired in your website so may be conflict?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
function myfunction(){

var address = document.location.href;
console.log(address);

}

if (window.attachEvent) {window.attachEvent('onload', myfunction);}
else if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('load', myfunction, false);}
else {document.addEventListener('load', myfunction, false);}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `document.readyState` in place of `window.onload` like this:

```
var timer_global;

function stub(){
    if(document.readyState=="complete"){
        clearInterval(timer_global);
        myfunction();   
    }

}
timer_global=setInterval(stub,200);
```

worked like a charm!! B-)